# how to login to a website and download a file in UNIX AIX 6.1

Tags: unix, aix

I need to login to a website which requires credentials. After that I need to click on a link (link url changes everyday but there will be only one link in the page). Once link is clicked file will be downloaded. I achieved this using selenium in windows not sure how to do it in UNIX. After my search in google I understood we can use wget or curl but we need to specify directly the url which I don't know before login.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a "hand wavey" answer.

Use curl or wget to get the first page.  It will be a text file.

Use tools like sed and grep to pull out the URL.  Then use curl / wget to get the target file.  If it is a simple page with one link, this should be rather easy to do.

You can get curl / wget from [perzl](http://www.perzl.org/aix/).